# show message in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

In asp.net crystal report how can i show message to user if records not found in particular values using  parameter value field?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a technique to handle similar situations.  See [Crystal Reports: Display a Message When Report Has No Data](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2007/08/28/crystal-reports-display-a-message-when-report-has-no-data/)